# Django: Adding User in a Group

Tags: python, django

Here's the model,

```
class Groupchat(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="admin")
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="members", blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I've no idea how can 'admin' add any user to the Group that he/she created.

How can I do that or at least what is the right way to do so?

Please helpme!

Comment: create a superuser using python manage.py createsuperuser , then register , go to 127.0.0.1:8000/admin , then login with credentials  , now you can change the users

Comment: The easiest way is to use Django's default admin panel, given you've setup a superuser and the admin panel properly. Follow Django documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a simple way to do it

```
new_user = User.objects.get(pk=1) #get the user
group = Groupchat.objects.get(pk=1) #get the group
group.members.add(new_user)
```

things can get more sophisticated as the system grows, but starting with a simple solution and evolving whats is necessary is a good idea

if only the group admin can add persons, all you have to do is on the request check the admin used_id session to see if the id = group_admin id, if is proceed to the query above